# JQuery ajax success help

Tags: jquery

I am implementing a "Quick delete" function into a page I am creating. The way it works is like this:

1: You click the "delete" button in the table row for the record that you want to delete.

2: The page sends a request to the ajax page and return a successfully message of "yes" or a failure message of "no".

My issue is that if I get a successful message of "yes" I want to hide the row for that record. I am having issue "finding" the row using JQuery.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".pane .btn-delete").click(function(){

    var element = $(this);
    var del_id = element.attr("id");
    var dataString = 'action=del&cid=' + del_id;

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this content block?"))
        {
        $("#msgbox").addClass('ajaxmsg').text('Checking permissions....').fadeIn(1000);

         $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: "ajax/admArticles_ajax.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(data){
               switch(data)
                {
                    case "yes":
                        $("#msgbox").addClass('ajaxmsg').text('Deleting content block....').fadeIn(1000);

                        $(this).parents(".pane").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")

                    break
                    case "no":
                        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('error').text('You do not have the correct permissions to delete this content....').fadeIn(1000);
                    break
                    default:
                    };
                }
         });

     }
    return false;
});
```

});

This is the lines of code I am using to hide the row however it is not working because I don't think $(this).parents(".pane") finds the element.

```
$(this).parents(".pane").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: It is not the opacity that is giving me issues. It is the $(this).parents(".pane"). It can't find the coreect row to delete. If I place the above code outside the "switch" statement it correctly hides the correct row. I am not sure if I need to pass the row along to the "success" function

Comment: If placing the code outside the switch statement (presumably still in the 'success' callback) causes it to work, it would seem that the switch is the issue. Have you verified the value of `data` that is returned?

Comment: Hi patrick, yes the data is return the string "yes". It is just that using $(this).parents(".pane") inside the switch statement does not find the correct row. 
If i change the code to $(".pane") it will remove all the rows of the table showing that it is working. This is not correct though because I only want to remove the One row.

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but placing the code outside the switch (yet still in the `success` callback) shouldn't make a difference to the selector. Have you tried referencing the row via your `element` variable instead of `$(this)`?

Comment: I am unsure how to reference the element not using $(this). I am pretty sure this is what is causing the issue. Thanks for you help on this.

Comment: You already have a variable in your function called `element`, so just do `element.parents("page")...`

Comment: I got it at last. I changed the code to:

$(element).parents(".pane").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast") as you said Patrick, thanks heaps...

Comment: Glad it worked. Looks like `this` has a different reference in a jQuery callback. I didn't realize that. I'll add an answer for clarity.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, .success() is deprecated. You want to use .done(), .fail(), and .always().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an Ajax callback, `this` does not reference your element that handled the event.

You have a reference to it already in your event handler called `element`, though. Just do:

```
element.parents(".pane").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i'm fairly certain that `opacity` is a numerical value of 0 to 1.

Thus, you should change your line to be `.animate({ opacity: "0" }...`